# listtile item is reappearing when i tried to remove form the listview

Tags: javascript, flutter, flutter-animation

I am working in flutter for few months. I have a problem in `Listview` items, when i removed a item of listtile using `removeWhere` fuction from the `snapshot.data` it reappears within a second.
Can any one help to hide the `listtile` item permanently from the snap shot.

see how it reappears ->:

[image]

This is my code snippet

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:need/credentials.dart';
import 'package:need/models.dart';
import 'package:need/shop/need_details_shop.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class shopOrders extends StatefulWidget {
  const shopOrders({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _shopOrdersState createState() => _shopOrdersState();
}

class _shopOrdersState extends State with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  Future _updateStatus(String orderId, String orderStatus) async {
    String uri = '$domain/shop/order/status/$orderId/$orderStatus';
    var response = await http.put(uri, headers: <String, String>{
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    });

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print("sucess");

    } else {
      print("failed");
    }
  }

  Future<List<Orders>> _fetchShopOrders() async {
    SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var sid = preferences.getString('shop_id');
    String uri = '$domain/shop/order/view/$sid';
    var response = await http.get(uri);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final items = json.decode(response.body).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
      List<Orders> listOfOrders = items.map<Orders>((json) {
        return Orders.fromJson(json);
      }).toList();

      return listOfOrders;
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load internet');
    }
  }

  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return Scaffold(
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Center(
                child: Column(children: <Widget>[
      Container(
          child: FutureBuilder<List<Orders>>(
        future: _fetchShopOrders(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData)
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());

          return ListView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            primary: false,
            children: snapshot.data
                .map((order) => Card(
                        child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Container(
                            height: 130,
                            width: 130,
                            child: Container(
                              color: Colors.grey,
                              child: Image(
                                  image: NetworkImage(order.product_photo),
                                  fit: BoxFit.fill),
                            )),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 20,
                        ),
                        Container(
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              Text(order.product_title.toUpperCase()),
                              Text("Price  " + order.product_price),
                              Text("Status" + " ..."),
                              Text(order.ordered_date),
                              Row(
                                children: [
                                  IconButton(
                                      icon: Icon(Icons.check,
                                          color: Colors.green),
                                      onPressed: () {
                                        String oid = order.order_id;
                                        String status = "delivered";
                                        _updateStatus(order.order_id, status);
                                        setState(() {
                                          snapshot.data.removeWhere(
                                              (order) => order.order_id == oid);
                                        });
                                      }),
                                  IconButton(
                                      icon:
                                          Icon(Icons.close, color: Colors.pink),
                                      onPressed: () {
                                        String oid = order.order_id;
                                        String status = "cancled";
                                        _updateStatus(order.order_id, status);
                                        setState(() {
                                          snapshot.data.removeWhere(
                                              (order) => order.order_id == oid);
                                        });
                                      })
                                ],
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    )))
                .toList(),
          );
        },
      ))
    ]))));
  }
}
```

Comment: you are deleting data from list not in db,you may need write api for delete from the dB or change status of data when deleting, every time the ui rebuilds the data reappears because it just delete from the list not from dB @1357 VENKATESH R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue happens because the UI gets rebuilt again each time you remove an item, which means the FutureBuilder is rebuilt again, triggering the API request which causes the item to be brought back, what I would do in a case like that is call the API request inside initstate and save the response, then build the UI based on it, maybe even add a bool that becomes true when the Future is loading and false when. it's done, I'll be happy to help further but I'll let you try it on your own first.

Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks a lot brother,you did a fantastic job and it works the way u said

Comment: but when i implement the same thing in resusable widget it makes it instance for a single but when i call it on other page it doesnt render the widget which made.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/venki1410/9a2cfb04be83543eb83842774f75ee29 this is the code sinppet